# Asymptotic distribution of MLE of $\theta$ for the pdf $f(x)=\frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{\theta+1}}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, delta-method

There's some questions:

> Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be iid random variables with common density function
>   $$f(x) = \frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{\theta+1}}   , x > 0 , \theta > 0 $$
>
> (a) Find the MLE of $\theta$. denote $\hat\theta_n$
>
> (b) Find the asymptotic distribution of  ${\sqrt n} (\hat\theta_n - \theta )$ (by Delta method)

The result of MLE is $ \hat\theta = \frac{1}{\log(1+X)} $ (but i'm not sure whether it's correct answer or not)

But I have no idea about how to compute (b). Can anybody help me?

The following is screen capture  from my question

[image]

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Done. Thanks you.

Comment: It is not clear where exactly you are stuck if you know the theory behind the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood function is
$$
L(\theta)=L(\theta\mid X_1,\dots,X_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\theta}{(1+X_i)^{\theta+1}},\quad \theta,X_1,\dots,X_n>0
$$
So
$$
\log L(\theta)=n\log\theta-(\theta+1)\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+X_i)
$$
giving MLE
$$
\hat\theta_n=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+X_i)}
$$
We have $Y_i=\log (1+X_i)$ follows an exponential distribution, so central limit theorem gives $\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y}-\mu_Y)$ is asymptotically $N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$ (I'll leave you to determine the $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y^2$).  Hence with $g(x)=1/x$, delta method tells you $\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta_n-\theta)$ is asymptotically $N(0,\sigma_Y^2\cdot[g'(g^{-1}(\theta))]^2)$.

Comment: Thanks you, I don't notice that Y follows exponential distribution ... Once I know then I could solve this problem. Appreciate!

Comment: Why did you change it to $g^{-1}(\theta)$?

Comment: $g(\mu_Y)=\theta$, $g(\bar{Y})=\hat\theta_n$ and the scaling factor is $g'(\mu_Y)^2$ rather than $g'(\theta)^2$ because we started with $\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y}-\mu_Y)$ asymptotically $N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$.

Comment: May I ask, why is $ [g′(g^−1(θ))]^2 $ but not $ [g'^-1(θ)]^2 $ ?

Comment: We start with $\sqrt{n}(\bar Y-\mu_Y)\xrightarrow{D}N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$ so $\sqrt{n}(g(\bar Y)-g(\mu_Y))\xrightarrow{D}N(0,\sigma_Y^2 [g'(\mu_Y)]^2)$ by delta method, right?  Now we make $g(\mu_Y)=\theta$ and $g(\bar Y)=\hat\theta_n$ and it turns out to be $g(x)=1/x$.

Comment: Very Very appreciate！　Very clear~